# Error: attempt to index nil with 'Agility'

Tags: lua, roblox

Having problems with one script, I'm getting this error:

> Workspace.AgilityZone.HitboxSide.Script:3: attempt to index nil with 'Agility'  -  Server - Script:3

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local player = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if player.Agility.Value >= script.Parent.Parent.Requirement.Value then
        player.ZoneMulti.Value = script.Parent.Parent.Multi.Value
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that `player` is nil, and that's because `game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)` isn't guaranteed to return a player. All you need to do is add some safety checks.

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local player = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)

    -- double check that we've got a player
    if not player then
        return
    end

    if player.Agility.Value >= script.Parent.Parent.Requirement.Value then
        player.ZoneMulti.Value = script.Parent.Parent.Multi.Value
    end
end)
```

Comment: Another option is to prepend `player and` to the original if statement condition

Comment: @Nifim, good suggestion, and that might be preferable if you want other stuff to happen when the object gets touched.